# load numpy.npy file on bash variable

Tags: python, bash, numpy, load

Say I have a `numpy.npy` file saved in my current directory which looks something like this:

```
[[0,10,456], [1,10, 876], [0,100, 34], [5,100,22]]
```

I would like to load this into a bash variable to the use in a for loop.
I tried the following:

```
 $ C=($(python -c "from numpy import load; print(load('numpy.npy'))"))
```

However, this reads the square brackets `[[`like an entry.
I tried printing a list comprehension, but that didn't get me far.

Last thing I tried is

```
D=($(python -c "from numpy import load; print(', '.join(['('+' '.join([str(n) for n in s])+')' for s in load('remaining_indxs.npy')]))"))
```

Is there some practical way to load a npy array into a bash variable, which doesn't involve elaborate in-line string modifications?  Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to remain as a 2D list?

Comment: you can try using `return ()` instead of print

Comment: That doesn't look like a .npy file, that looks like someone wrote the `str` representation of a list to a file as text, especially if there are bracket's.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's to give an idea of how the array looks, ie is has shape (4,3). if loaded with numpy.load into a variable (in python environment) and then printed, it looks like that

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri I get a SyntaxError because return is outside a function

Comment: @chrisz yes. I also tried creating an array of strings of the format `D=("0 10 45" "1 01 876" "0 100 34" "5 100 22")`, but I'm still working on it

Comment: What is this Bash variable supposed to look like?  A pointer to a python object in a dead process?  Some sort of string representation of the array?  A next list of numbers? flat list of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [386]: alist = [[0,10,456], [1,10, 876], [0,100, 34], [5,100,22]]
In [387]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [388]: np.save('afile.npy',arr)
```

In another terminal I can run the Python command

```
1032:~/mypy$ python3 -c "from numpy import load;print(load('afile.npy'))"
[[  0  10 456]
 [  1  10 876]
 [  0 100  34]
 [  5 100  22]]
```

and redirect the stdout to a file:

```
1034:~/mypy$ python3 -c "from numpy import load;print(load('afile.npy'))">afile.txt
1034:~/mypy$ cat afile.txt
[[  0  10 456]
 [  1  10 876]
 [  0 100  34]
 [  5 100  22]]
```

That's the same sort of text I get in the `ipython` session from `arr`:

```
[391]: arr     # repr display
Out[391]: 
array([[  0,  10, 456],
       [  1,  10, 876],
       [  0, 100,  34],
       [  5, 100,  22]])
In [392]: print(arr)      # str display
[[  0  10 456]
 [  1  10 876]
 [  0 100  34]
 [  5 100  22]]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @hpaulj , I was also thinking of outputting everything to a txt file. However, this still bears the problem: how to use this array in a bash variable? I think this cannot be achieved. I read that bash variables do not support multi-dimensional array structure